# How can I plot the country name in R over a map using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

Hello everyone I have generated a map of some south american countries as

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


p=c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Venezuela",
         "Colombia", "Bolivia")

mp<-map_data("world", region=p) 

mlola <- mp %>%  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarize(mlo= mean(long), mla=mean(lat))


ggplot(mapa_paises,aes( x= long, y = lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_polygon( )+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))
```

Now I want to plot the names of the countries using the variable `mlola`, which contains positions inside of each country. However, I don't know how to do it. I think it can be done using [geom_text](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html), however, all my attempts have failed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are plotting x, y data, you will get reasonable results with a simple mean of latitude and longitude for the label positions:

```r
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p <- c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", 
       "Ecuador", "Peru", "Venezuela", "Colombia", "Bolivia")

mp <- map_data("world", region = p)

ggplot(mp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = region)) +
  geom_polygon(col = "gray75", alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise_all(mean),
            aes(label = region), size = 5, fontface = 2, color = "gray20") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. I was windering if I could also mark the capitals of the countries, e.g. -34.1 N, -58.06 E is the location of Buenos Aires. My idea was to create another vector such as `mlola <- mp %>%  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarize(mlo= mean(long), mla=mean(lat))` however, I don't know how to do it with your solution

Comment: @slow_learner Do you have the co-ordinates of each city?

Comment: Lets go with  -34.1 N, -58.06 E for Buenos Aires and -12N, -77 E for Lima, I will try to figure the rest later

Comment: You could do `+ annotate(geom = "text", x = c(-58.06, -77), y = c(-34.1, -12), labels = c("Buenos Aires", "Lima"))`

Comment: Thanks again, however, I obtain the following error now`Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`. I have added this just after the code you sent me

Comment: @slow_learner sorry, that should be `label` rather than `labels`